# How much does it cost for wrong format of Ethereum transaction?(e.g. wrong account nonce)

Tags: ethereum, nonce, fee

I heard that if Ethereum transaction fails for some reason, then remaining gas is refunded. But what if the transaction's nonce is wrong? If you deliberately propagate the same nonce transaction from an account, it is judged to be wrong transactions, so the receiving node will ignore the transaction, or will consider it fail and only refund a part of the gas?

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46827/is-the-gas-fee-refunded-if-the-transaction-fails

If the latter is right, then how much does it cost for wrong transaction format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't cost you any ether(gas), because when the nodes receive a transaction with, for example, a wrong nonce, they will simply discard this transaction from its transaction pool after a period of time.

Since the transaction will not be executed nor written into a block, the gas will not be consumed.